# UITableView "selection" triggered segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am using `Storyboard` and `UITableView` without `UINavigationController`.

When tapping on any cell, it should bring user to a detail page. I can of course implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

But I wished to try something fairly different. I want to do it with a storyboard `segue`. I use prototype cell, and I can simply config a triggered segue on the cell. I can implement `prepareForSegue:`, but here's the problem, how can I know what cell has been selected?

[image: Xcode Screen]

Comment: even if you get the solution for your question, make sure that you had gone through tha tutorial in my answer for efficient use of storyboard, using storyboard has several advantages and disadvantages

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `prepareForSegue:sender:` method's `sender` parameter is the cell you are looking for. You can get it's index path by `[self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender]` (you may need a cast).

Answer (score 1):

to get a clear view about how to use storyboard please check the following tutorial, [how to use Storyboard](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

make sure that you read the second part too....this will give you a clear idea how to use, and the solution for your question also is there.